# Add Javascript code only to the last textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding a `WYSIWYG` text editor. In this, I only want the last textarea to display the `WYSIWYG` text editor and the top 3 text editors should be the same. How can i edit the `selector` so it'll only effect the 4th text editor given below.

```
<script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});</script>


<textarea>Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea>
<textarea>Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea>
<textarea>Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea>
<textarea>Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to modify the markup, try this:

```
<script>tinymce.init({selector:'textarea:last-child'});</script>
```

Could also use jQuery:

```
<script>tinymce.init({selector:'$("textarea").last()'});</script>
```

... or

```
<script>tinymce.init({selector:'$("textarea").eq(3)'});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({elements :'txtwysiwyg'});</script>


<textarea>Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea>
<textarea>Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea>
<textarea>Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea>
<textarea id="txtwysiwyg">Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give one of the `textarea`'s an ID so that you can reference that in your tinyMCE initialization. I'd suggest spending some time reading over the docs they have a lot of great examples

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php

```
<script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({selector:'#tinyMCE'});</script>


<textarea>Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea>
<textarea>Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea>
<textarea>Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea>
<textarea id="tinyMCE">Easy! You should check out MoxieManager!</textarea>
```